# How do I read raw code from a website in Gforth?

Tags: networking, forth, gforth

I would like a word like

```
read-site ( add n buff max -- n flag )
```

where 'add n' is the site name buffer, 'buff max' is the buffer to which the ASCII text should be read to, 'n' is the number of bytes that was read and `flag` is true if operation succeeded.

Is this possible in Gforth in Linux, Android or Windows?

Comment: you may get site content as a local file (or memory block) & then use  something like : read-lines ( fileid -- )
  begin  pad max-line third read-line throw
  while  pad swap  ( fileid c-addr u )  \ string excludes the newline
         2drop
  repeat 2drop ; to read it ...   maybe ... what exactly are you expecting to get from the sites?

Comment: @francoisP: I want to collect data to be analyzed. :)

Comment: @francoisP: I also have an idea of design my own search function in Forth. Some sites are truly valuable (if the trash is filtered away) but almost all search functions are too limited.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

#### Just a list of approaches

The most easy proper way should be to use an HTTP-client library (or binding) in Forth (if any). It seems that some kind of such library exists in the Gforth repository — see [netlib/httpclient.fs](https://github.com/earl/gforth-mirror/blob/master/netlib/httpclient.fs). Obviously it doesn't work with HTTPS.

The next way is to use an appropriate external shared library, for example [*libcurl*](https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/). It is well-known tool that supports a lot of protocols (the binding and some usage examples can be also found in SP-Forth).

The next way is to use a system call and spawn a child process (not so efficient approach in terms of resources usage). Gforth has [`system`](https://www.complang.tuwien.ac.at/forth/gforth/Docs-html/Passing-Commands-to-the-OS.html) word for that. Usage example:

```
S" curl http://example.com/" system
```

The web-page HTML code will be printed to stdout. Unfortunately, redirection with [`outfile-execute`](https://www.complang.tuwien.ac.at/forth/gforth/Docs-html/Redirection.html) doesn't work in this case (it looks like incomplete or weak implementation of the `system` word).

So, a temporary file should be used:

```
S" curl --silent http://example.com/ > tmp" system
```

After that the file content can be read into a given buffer.

A conceptual implementation is the following:

```
: read-url ( d-buffer d-txt-url -- d-txt-webpage )
  s" curl --silent {} > tmp" interpolate system
  over >r \ keep buf addr
  s" tmp" open-file throw dup >r read-file throw
  r> close-file throw
  r> swap
;
```

where `interpolate ( i*x d-txt1 -- d-txt2 )` expands the given template.

Comment: Yes, along with HTTPS, cURL also supports FTP, SCP, and many other protocols, see the [official web-site](https://curl.haxx.se/).

Comment: Great! BTW, can I somehow load SP-Forth for Ubuntu?

Comment: Your concept works for GForth under Ubuntu, but not under Android. Thanks again!

Comment: To install SP-Forth in Ubuntu the old [deb package](http://downloads.sourceforge.net/spf/spforth4_4.20-1_i386.deb) from http://spf.sf.net/ can be used.